# Identity Server without Login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, authorization, identityserver4, asp.net-authorization

Im trying to implement IdentityServer authorization and my scenario is below:

we have one home page for all our application "www.vision2025.com" and i have link to my mvc application "MarketingDashboard" where users are authenticated by home page and redirect to my mvc application using windows authentication. Now user can do any action in my dashboard which interact to web API.

Now i need to implemented IdentityServer to authorize all the web API call from my dashboard but no need of login.

Please suggest any idea

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't want to build `IdentityServer` because your enterprise company has already built ADFS (Active Directory Federation Services). You just want to ask who maintain AD and ask him to enable ADFS for OAuth2. This is a page to help you catch all scenarios [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/overview/ad-fs-openid-connect-oauth-flows-scenarios).

Because I don't know how far you can change for all applications but there are some solutions with ADFS you can go with:

1. Let your main server (acts as Home Page and where user redirects to ADFS to sign in) performs [On-behalf-Of flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/overview/ad-fs-openid-connect-oauth-flows-scenarios#on-behalf-of-flow). In this scenario, your main server will be a linked server that transfer its taken `access token` which retrieved from ADFS. I strongly recommend this way because you just want to add as many as your new upcoming web and api. The cons are they require you ensure protect highly `access token` in your main server
2. Because `OAuth 2.0` doesn't support chaining Resource Servers yet (such as you signed in Resource Server A, then use `provided access_token` to call Resource Server B in different clients), you need to allow your main server **store his username/password** (also knew as **trusted back end server** , means your enterprise allows this server can store client credentials). So each time you redirect user to target MVC Application, you should transfer **encrypted username/password** as well. Then your target MVC application can perform [Authorized Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/overview/ad-fs-openid-connect-oauth-flows-scenarios#authorization-code-grant-flow) or [Implicit flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/overview/ad-fs-openid-connect-oauth-flows-scenarios#implicit-grant-flow)  itself in Back-end code, then returned new `access token` to client web to perform calling Web API.

Comment: Thanks @johnathan-le its great idea but  many application (more than 25 mvc app) are in home page and each mvc application have their own Web API, so  for us now its easy to apply token authorization for my MVC app and Web API . So your help and guidance will be more helpful.

Comment: @KARTHIKEYANDEIVASENAKANTHAN Just updated my answer